# Como resolver renderização de html com VUE?

Tags: wordpress, rest, vue.js

estou fazendo um teste com a rest-api do wordpress com vue 2.x, e um dos atributos retornado é o seguinte:

```
"content":  {
    "rendered": "<P>Bem-vindo ao WordPress. Esse é o seu primeiro post. Edite-o ou exclua-o, e então comece a escrever!</P>\n"
},
```

Aí na minha página o "p" do html é exibido. Tentei resolver com `{{{  }}}` mas a versão reconhece mais dessa forma. E com `v-html` também dá erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Vue.js 2 tens de usar o `v-html` que recebe a variável que tem o HTML que queres usar:

```js
var data = {
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<P>Bem-vindo ao WordPress. Esse é o seu primeiro post. Edite-o ou exclua-o, e então comece a escrever!</P>\n"
    }
};

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data
});
```

```html
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <div v-html="content.rendered"></div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58toLeoL/